# jQuery Event Chaining and Form Not Submitting

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I wrote a PHP library that generates server-side validation code as well as client-side (jQuery) validation code.  Here's my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/W5d7e/2/.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var contactMessageInputValidationFunction = function () {
    if ($.trim($("#contactMessageInput").val()).length > 0) {
        $("#contactMessageInputErrorMessage").hide();
        return true;
    } else {
        $("#contactMessageInputErrorMessage").show();
        return false;
    }
};

$("#contactMessageInput").blur(contactMessageInputValidationFunction).parents("form").submit(contactMessageInputValidationFunction);
});
```

In my example, on input blur, we check to see if the input is empty, and if it is, we show an error message.  I also run this validation function on form submit, and if it returns false (invalid input), the form doesn't submit.

Here's the problem:  press the Send button, which will show the error message.  Then, type a message into the textarea, and immediately click the Submit button again afterwards.  The error message disappears, but the form isn't submitted until you press Send again.  Why do I need to press it a second time?  Is my validation function incorrect in some way?  Is the way I chained the events incorrect?

For reference, I'm using Chrome 31.0.

Thanks!

Comment: It triggers on blur, so you have to remove focus from whatever input you're typing in before hitting the submit button.

Comment: Oh, and the button moves on blur, so it's hard to hit in the fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W5d7e/3/

Comment: `if (function () {
            return $.trim($("#contactMessageInput").val()).length > 0;
        }())`  looks weird

Comment: That's fine that it triggers blur, but why is the blur event blocking the submission of the form when I click Submit?  In my head, clicking Submit seems like it should trigger both.

Comment: @A. Wolff, yeah, sorry.  I removed that part just now.  It's there because what's evaluated in the if statement is usually a long function returned by the PHP that is generating the form validation.  In other words, it's not always just boolean logic that goes there, so it needs to be wrapped up in a closure that returns a boolean.

Comment: @adeneo Is the mousedown on the Send button causing the validation to occur, which removes the message, causing the mouseup to occur off the Send button?  Maybe that's why it doesn't register the form submission.

Comment: Well, in your fiddle it seems the blur event removes the error message, and that moves the submit button, so it's never really clicked as you're not hitting it, it moves. In the fiddle I posted above I just moved the error message below the other elements so the submit button doesn't move, and it seems to work fine on first click for me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@adeneo got it right. If you enter nothing, press "Send", then enter something, then MOUSEDOWN (not mouseup) on "Send", blur() is triggered on the input, which removes the error message and causes the "Send" button to move upwards. When it does so, your mouse is no longer over the button, and so you don't mouseup on the button. For the form to submit, you must mousedown and mouseup while the mouse is over the "Send" button.

Comment: yes this is correct and this fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/Q3P7D/` may assist in debugging this behaviour.